# Chinese modern vocabulary 包饺子

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, food

What would be the correct translation for 包饺子 ?
Is it a word of 3 hanzi, or just a sentence wrap...  dumplings ?
包 is used as a verb or a name ?
Many dictionaries give " to wrap meat dumpling ", and 包 is also a measure word!
What about the verb to stuff ?  stuffed dumplings ?

thanking you

Answer (score 2):

包餃子 just means to *make (wrap) dumplings* - it is not a three character word. Consider the similar phrase

> 包傷口
>
> *To dress wounds* (wrap wounds in bandages)

To say *to stuff*, you can use the verb 塡 (*to fill*).

> 把餡料塡進火鷄裏
>
> *Put the stuffing in the turkey*

Answer (score 1):

Many Chinese characters have multiple functions

> 包 http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/373/
>
> [1] [v] wrap; pack; bundle
>
> [2] [n] [classifier] package; bundle; sack; packet; parcel
>
> [3] [n] bun (food)
>
> [4] [v] include; contain; cover
>
> [5] [v] undertake; guarantee; assure
>
> [6] [v] charter; hire; contract
>
> [7] [v] surround; encircle; envelop

包 in 包饺子 is a verb for "to wrap"

To pack filling into bun is called "包饀" (包 is verb ; 饀 is noun)

'to stuff' filling into food items in Chinese is 釀 as in 釀豆腐, 釀青椒

'to fill' sausage in Chinese is 灌 as in 灌香腸

Answer (score 1):

While this could be construed as a construct of 包 and 饺子, I'd argue that it is a single word.

*ABC* and *KEY* both list 包饺子 as a

> VO

a verb-object word.

*ABC* even defines it as:

> 1 V.O. wrap meat dumplings
>
> 2 COLL. surround and annihilate

Especially now that 包饺子 has a phrasal usage it is more likely to be considered a single word - one with a literal meaning and one with a figurative meaning.